# Threshold lower than $\dfrac{n}{2}$ in distributed key generation

Tags: key-generation, threshold-cryptography

While I was studying protocols for distributed key generation with malicious adversaries, Gennaro et al.$^{[1]}$ pointed out that the protocols that provide both secrecy and robustness should have a threshold lower than $\dfrac{n}{2}$. However, I do not see how the robustness of the scheme can compromise the secrecy of the protocol in the case of a threshold higher than $\dfrac{n}{2}$.

Does someone have an explanation for this?

---

[1] R. Gennaro, S. Jarecki, H. Krawczyk, and T. Rabin, “Secure distributed key
generation for discrete-log based cryptosystems,” in International Conference on the Theory and Applications of Cryptographic Techniques, pp. 295–
310, Springer, 1999.

Comment: The [reference version of the paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s00145-006-0347-3.pdf) is that [in Journal of Crytology, 2007](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00145-006-0347-3). It supersedes the [one in the question](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-48910-X_21.pdf), which was [in proceedings of Eurocrypt 1999](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-48910-X_21).